# How do i make a radio button link to a page using a button

Tags: html, button, radio-button

How do i make a radio button which can link to a page each radio button having being linked to a website and when i press a button i want it to direct me to the selected radio buttons link and i do not want it to be onclick i want it to direct me when i press the button. I have tried doing this but i need help.
This is what i tried:

```
    <h3>
Which part of the building do you want cleaning
</h3>
<form name="frmSite" style="float: left; margin-top: 5px;"> 
  <a class="loginPg_choices" href="www.youtube.com">
    <input type="radio" name="site" value="1" id="radio_btn_1" style="float: left; clear: both;" />
    <span style="float: left; margin: -2px 0 0 5px;">The whole building</span>
    <br/> 
  </a>
  <a class="loginPg_choices" href="www.google.com">
    <input type="radio" name="site" value="1" id="radio_btn_1" style="float: left; clear: both;" />
    <span style="float: left; margin: -2px 0 0 5px;">Kithcen</span>
    <br/> 
  </a>
  <a href="#" type="submit" value="Submit" title="Login" style="float: right; clear: both;">
    Submit
  </a>
</form>
```

Here is what i have tried https://jsfiddle.net/nb7jmfxp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) is the fieldset documentation.

Html code:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Choose your Website</legend>

    <input type="radio" id="youtube" name="monster">
    <label for="youtube">Youtube</label><br />

    <input type="radio" id="google" name="monster">
    <label for="google">Google</label><br />

  </fieldset>
</form>
<button id="go_to_website">
  Go to website
</button>
```

Js code:

```
  $("#go_to_website").click(function(event) {
    var link_id = $("input[name='monster']:checked").attr("id");
    if (link_id) {
      switch (link_id) {
        case "youtube":
          // code block
          window.location.href = 'www.youtube.com';
          break;
        case "google":
          // code block
          window.location.href = 'www.google.com';
          break;
        default:
          // code block
      }
    } else {
      alert("please pick an option")
    }
  })
```

Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/pc62oL74/4/

Hope that it helps.